# Jquery Cycle navigation won't show up in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, navigation, cycle

I am using the jQuery Cycle Plugin for a slideshow and the navigation shows up in all browsers I have tested, except IE7 (and IE6 but I'm not worried about that).

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/WVGS3/11/ (look at it on IE7, obviously)

When I look at it on IE7, the navigation disappears. As if it doesn't like the empty `.slide_nav` div. If I type some text within the `.slide_nav` div, the navigation appears along with whatever text I wrote.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/WVGS3/12/

I place the text within a span element and set `text-indent:-9999px` but that makes everything disappear. I used `display:none` and `display:hidden` but they behave oddly.

Perhaps I am missing something.

Anyone know of anything that will work here? I've tried using `position:relative`, `z-index:1000`, `zoom:1`, on parent and child elements but nothing works....

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put at least one `&nbsp;` inside the `div` as follows only for IE's [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)

```
<div class="slide_nav">&nbsp;</div>
```

Then you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        pager: ".slide_nav"
    });
    // Re align
    var ml=parseInt($('.slide_nav').css('margin-left'));
    $('.slide_nav').css('margin-left',(ml-5)+'px');

});​
```

Tested in IE7, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WVGS3/14/). May be not appropriate but solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot Sheikh! That definitely worked. Appropriate or not, that works for me. So could you breifly tell me what happens here. Are you adding the break there for it to reveal the div, and then moving the slide_nav backwards using jquery?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the hasLayout link also!

Comment: Thanks and yes I've just added `&nbsp; non-breakable space` and it increases 5px of empty space so I re-aligned the element by -5px of it's margin.